# Adding Custom Back Button on NavigationBar UIButton buttonWithTypw:101 not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I had used the below mention code for a custom left pointed back button and it was working properly..
but after a few days, it changed back to a rectangular button..
can anyone help me to get it back to its original type....
Thanks...

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem* newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
graphSecondViewCtrl.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button type 101 is not defined in the SDK, and can stop working at any OS upgrade.

I'd use a `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom` and then add an image that gives you the look you need by calling setImage:forState on the custom button object.

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBarButtonNormal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBarButtonHighlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

// Rest of the code is the same.
```

The real question is why you'd need to recreate the standard button that the navigation controller automatically gives you in the first place. Make sure you work with the tools, and not against them.

If you need to track when the view controller gets swapped in and out, you can set your view controller to be the delegate of the navigation controller like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (viewController != self)
        NSLog(@"We're going away...");
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[self navigationController] setDelegate:nil];
}
```

Comment: the thing is that, i have to set few tags in my code when a back button is pressed. this can't be done if a default back button is used. I created this custom button, so that page can go back and i can call my functions.. is there any alternate solution..

Comment: Absolutely! UINavigationController has a delegate that will be notified when a view controller is shown. You can just implement a delegate and update as needed when the view controllers are swapped in and out.

Comment: i found the delegate fns willShowViewController and didShowViewController.. but i m not sure how to use them. Could you plz help me.. there are 3 screens in my navigation view. both the back buttons call different backAction methods..

Comment: I updated the answer to show an example use of the navigation controller delegate. You could also just implement viewWillDisappear: if all you need to know is when the view controller is not the visible one.

Comment: thanks... its working now, but now i have another problem.. though the back button is working properly, it is shown on the view.. if i use [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; or any other button type its visible on the screen..

Answer (score 0):

The button type `101` is undocumented. It is not something Apple has agreed to maintain so it can change any time. It is incorrect to rely on such stuff. You should consider a `custom` button with images to be sure that it will not break like it has for you now.